# How to temporary select and edit some lines in a buffer?

Tags: emacs

I'm stuck on this problem. I have a file with almost 10k lines. Some of them should be deleted and I can get an hint from their content, e.g. if they contains a certain pattern "xyz", maybe they must be deleted. So, my idea is to:
* select only those lines containing each pattern in my list
* manually inspect them and change the ones actually to be deleted prepending them a "--" (or similar)
* ...and at the very end, delete all the lines starting with "--".
As `keep-lines` actually delete all the un-kept lines (TIL), is there any other way to do what I need? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `flush-lines` is the inverse of `keep-lines`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea would be to use M-x occur to select possible candidates.  Then, use "e" in the *Occur* buffer to enter "Occur Edit Mode".  In this mode, edits in the Occur buffer are reflected into the originating buffer.  So maybe you can just delete lines there altogether.

Comment: It's a good thought, but deleting lines entirely is one of the things you *can't* do in occur edit mode. However, you *can* mark the lines you wish to delete with some kind of token (e.g. "DELETEME") which you could do with an interactive search & replace in the occur buffer, and then back in the original buffer use `M-x flush-lines RET DELETEME RET`

Answer (score 1):

You might like to try `M-x all`.  It's like `M-x occur` except that buffer changes get propagated to the original buffer.  `all` can be installed from GNU ELPA (i.e. via `M-x list-packages`).

Comment: Occur-mode can propagate changes back to the originating buffer; in an Occur buffer, you can use `e` to allow editing, then make the desired changes.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could do this with `query-replace-regexp`.

1. `M-C-%` (or `M-x query-replace-regexp`)
2. Enter `^.*xyz.*$` as your search term and leave the replace term blank (hit enter)
3. Inspect each matching line in turn, hit `space` to delete or `n` to leave. Make sure you start at the beginning of the buffer to catch everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can get [hide-lines](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideLines) and use `M-x hine-lines-not-matching`.  Since it's still the same buffer (just displayed differently), you can edit the visible lines as you wish.